# What's the meaning of 'about' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence and I have no idea about the usage of "about" here. Can you please explain the meaning and usage of "about" in this sentence?

> This is not what people would have wanted to hear, but this was my experience of the war. It was training and transfers and even more training. It was **about** weekend passes and my first visit to California beach, where I laid eyes on the Pacific for the very first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it now. It means that it (the experience) was about ....
If it's not the right answer, please correct me.